# How do I get system property from teamcity in msbuild file?

Tags: msbuild, teamcity

How do I get system property from teamcity in msbuild file?

teamcity version:6.0

Comment: Ben Hall has a good [post with pics](http://blog.benhall.me.uk/2008/06/team-city-update-assemblyinfo-with.html) that helped me....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try removing `system_` part from property's name.

The documentation says

> - Don't forget to leave the "system." part out of the system
>     properties.
> - When using MSBuild, replace "." with "_" when you    reference
>     property names.

(However this is version 6.5 documentation, maybe it woun't work in your case but you can try it anyway)

Answer (score 1):

Just use `$(system_property_name)` in your MSBuild file.

Comment: I tried this in my build file, but both property values are empty.<PropertyGroup>
 <Version>$(system_build_number)</Version>
 <DepVersion>$(dep_bt30_system_build_number)</DepVersion>
 </PropertyGroup>

Comment: What about `<Version>$(build_number)</Version>`? It should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <Version>$(BUILD_NUMBER)</Version>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Yes, that works. The trouble here is that I also need to get dependent build number. What I did is to create a system property and assign dependent build number to it, then I can use this system property in build file. e.g. Name: system.dep.build.number, Value: %dep.bt23.build.number%. Now, in msbuild file, you can use $(dep_build_number) to get dependent build number.