# Build Number in SQL Azure

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database, assemblyinfo, auto-versioning

I have an Azure web service and accompanying sql-azure db that both need to expose a version number.
The service is straight forward: update the assemblyinfo to generate based on revision & build, and just expose that.

How can I do something similar in the db?
I had toyed with an auto-incremented number, but that increments the 'version' even if I deploy the same bits twice and does not guarantee continuity across servers with the same bits.
And, because it's sql-azure, I don't believe I can pull the value from assemblyinfo, can I?

If I can expose the same build number the service shows, that'd be great, but it's not required.

Answer (score 1):

1. Have a Version table in the database
2. Use a [custom MSBuild Task](http://weblogs.asp.net/bradleyb/archive/2005/12/02/432150.aspx) to get the build number
3. You can update a sql file with the ['MERGE'](http://benchmarkitconsulting.com/colin-stasiuk/2009/02/27/merge-statement-upsert-with-working-example/) with build number using [FileUpdate MSBuild community task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8658972/using-msbuild-i-want-to-update-a-config-file-with-values-from-teamcity)
4. Execute it as part of deployment.

Now, you'll have same version number in both database & your assemblies.