# How to have TeamCity update the build version number in a specified file?

Tags: javascript, teamcity, build-automation, amd

Does anyone know of an easy way to show the build version number in an HTML/JavaScript project that uses AMD?

The version number is generated by TeamCity as part of the build process.

Here is what I mean in more details:

One of my js files (e.g. showVersion.js) has a line like this:

```
  alert('Build version: __build_ver_placeholder__ ');
```

Ideally, after TeamCity completes the build, it will plug in the actual version number for the place-holder.
And the line above will become:

```
  alert('Build version: 2.1.0 ');
```

That way, the user can know the build version number by clicking a button on an HTML page which calls the alert() function.

Any idea will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Is version no an environment variable?

Comment: You have to write a script to update your files.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can simply add PowerShell build step containing the following code:

```
(Get-Content "showVersion.js") 
| Foreach { $_ -Replace "__build_ver_placeholder__", "%build.number%" } 
| Set-Content "showVersion.js";
```

**%build.number%** variable will be replaced by TeamCity during the build

Comment: Thanks very much Alexander. Although I haven't tried your suggestion yet, it looks promising!

Comment: For me it only worked if I put everything in one line.